# Append an item into an array inside a struct

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

Working on solidity 8.12, I have two structs, namely `singer` and `event`, two arrays one for singers and another for events. I want to write down a function that creates an event, specifying the singer id, and automatically append the event id into the array of events attended by the singer:

````
struct Singer {
uint id;
uint[] events_ids; // THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO UPDATE WITH THE NEW EVENT ID
}

struct Event {
uint id;
uint singer_id;
}

singer[] public SingerList;
event[] public EventList;
uint public n_singers;
uint public n_events;

    function CreateEvent(uint singer_id) external {
        if (singer_id > n_singers) { // singer id greater than the number of current singers.
            revert SingerIdError(singer_id);
        }
        else if (singer_id == n_singers){ // the singer does not exist yet! Create it!
            n_singers ++;
-------->   SingerList.push(Singer(singer_id))); // HOW TO APPEND THE EVENT ID TO THE LIST OF EVENTS IN SINGER STRUCT?
            EventList.push(Event(n_events, singer_id));
            
        }

        else { // the pilot already exists
            Singer storage _singer = SingerList[singer_id];
            _singer.event_ids.push(n_events);
            EventList.push(Event(n_events, n_events));
        }
        n_events ++;
    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

Using 'mapping' instead of array-of-struct, gives you better control over your state variables with no extra hassles to control the array indexes. It also costs lower gas fee.

```
mapping(uint => uint[]) Singer;
mapping(uint => uint[]) Event;
uint public n_singers;
uint public n_events;

function CreateEvent(uint singer_id) external {
    if(singer_id > n_singers) {
        revert SingerIdError(singer_id);
    }
    else if (singer_id == n_singers) {
        n_singers ++;
        Singer[singer_id].push(n_events); // HOW TO APPEND THE EVENT ID TO THE LIS....
        Event[n_events].push(singer_id);
    } else {
        Singer[singer_id].push(n_events);
    }
    n_events++;
}`
```